# Representation of any signal using unit signal

Tags: signal, signal-processing, basic, homework, signal-theory

I was introduced to the unit step signal and told that we can write any discontinuous signal in terms of the unit step signal to omit the discontinuity from the mathematical expression.

So if we are to write the following signal we can do the following:

[image]

So x(t) = u(t-2) - u(t-4)

This is generally what books say, but we can also write x(t) as the multiplication of the following two functions:

[image]

So x(t) = u(t-2) · u(-t+4)

Why is there only mention of the first way of solving the problem, while the other one is never talked about? What is wrong with the other approach?

Comment: It is simpler to use additive functions than multiplying ... ?

Comment: That's an unit step signal, not an unit impulse.